# Create a dictionary from two lists and then print the data in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am new to python and am trying to grasp a few things. I would like to create a dictionary from two lists. I have two sets of data:

```
Person  |    Name
--------|--------
1       |   Jimmy
2       |    Mike
3       | Stanley
4       |    Will
```

I have both of these in lists, one called "person" and one called "name". I do this in a script which runs through multiple files to pull the data. each list is a different length with different data in it. Essentially, what I want to do is print the data as like this:

```
1 \t Jimmy
2 \t Mike
3 \t Stanley
4 \t Will
```

I pull the data from an xml file and here is the code I use to pull the data:

```
for people in xml.iter('people'):
  person.append(people.find('person').text)
  name.append(people.find('name').text)
```

So far the script works great and I can print out the two lists separately. What I don't know how to do is print them out together and so my thought is to store them to a dictionary instead, but I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: The lists look like they're the same length, but you said "each list is a different length"... which is it?

Comment: Yes, they two (person and name) lists will always be the same length. This script runs through multiple xml files, so for each xml file, the sets will be different lengths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to print the two lists you can use `zip` [(doc)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for num,name in zip(num_list,name_list):
    print str(num) + '\t' + name
```

you can use the same form to put the pairs in a dictionary (after you have the lists)

```
name_dict = {}
for num,name in zip(num_list,name_list):
    name_dict[num] = name
```

and then print

```
for num,name in name_dict.iteritems():
    print str(num) + '\t' + name
```

Comment: Ahh very cool. I will give this a shot! I didn't know about this.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need a dict here. To pair the elements of lists together, just use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [27]: zip(person, name)
Out[27]: [(1, 'Jimmy'), (2, 'Mike'), (3, 'Stanley'), (4, 'Will')]
```

---

For example,

```
person = [1,2,3,4]
name = ['Jimmy', 'Mike', 'Stanley', 'Will']
for p, n in zip(person, name):
    print('{p}\t{n}'.format(p = p, n = n))
```

yields

```
1   Jimmy
2   Mike
3   Stanley
4   Will
```

---

PS. If, for some reason, you do want a dict, it is easy to form too:

```
In [28]: dict(zip(person, name))
Out[28]: {1: 'Jimmy', 2: 'Mike', 3: 'Stanley', 4: 'Will'}
```

Answer (score 2):

In elementary python.

```
people_dict = {}
for people in xml.iter('people'):
  person = people.find('person').text
  name = people.find('name').text
  people_dict[name] = person
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the dict using the zip builtin function:

```
dct = dict(zip(person, name))
```

Then to print the dict, you can do something like this:

```
for k in dct:
    print '%s\t%s' % (k, dct[k])
```

good luck

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is print them out together, then a list of tuples might be more appropriate than a dictionary, since a dictionary does not maintain order.  Here is how you could do this:

```
people = []
for person in xml.iter('people'):
    people.append((person.find('person').text, person.find('name').text))
```

Then to print:

```
for p, name in people:
    print p + '\t' + name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function.

```
In [3]: person = range(1,5)

In [4]: name = ['Jimmy', 'Mike', 'Stanley', 'Will']

In [5]: zip(person, name)
Out[5]: [(1, 'Jimmy'), (2, 'Mike'), (3, 'Stanley'), (4, 'Will')]

In [6]: for p,n in zip(person, name):
   ...:     print p, '\t', n
   ...:     
1   Jimmy
2   Mike
3   Stanley
4   Will
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Python 2.7 or newere, [Dict comprehensions](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/dict-comprehensions.html) are available.  They may be overkill for your particular situation, but they are a good technique to know and resolve this issue gracefully.